# Diferencias entre Rvalue y Lvalue

Tags: c++, c++11

Desde hace un tiempo en algunos blogs aparecen dos términos que no termino de comprender: `Rvalue` y `Lvalue`. Sin tener claro el significado de ambos términos el contenido de determinados ejemplos se hace complicado de entender.

1. ¿Qué diferencias hay entre un `Rvalue` y un `Lvalue`?
2. ¿Cómo se puede identificar cada uno?
3. ¿Qué se puede hacer y qué no con cada uno de ellos?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

En [este artículo de MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90831hc.aspx) hay una explicación breve y bastante clara. Te traduzco (énfasis mío):

Todas las expresiones de C++ son o un *lvalue* o un *rvalue*. **Un lvalue es un objeto que persiste más allá de una expresión**. Se puede pensar en un *lvalue* como en un objeto que tiene un nombre. Todas las variables, incluyendo las no modificables (const) son *lvalues*.

**Un rvalue es un valor temporal que no persiste más allá de la expresión en la que se usa**.

Para entender mejor la diferencia entre *lvalue* y *rvalue*, considera el siguiente ejemplo:

```
// lvalues_y_rvalues1.cpp
// compilar con: /EHsc
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int x = 3 + 4;
   cout << x << endl;
}
```

Aquí `x` es un *lvalue* porque persiste más allá de la expresión que lo define. La expresión 3+4 es un *rvalue* porque se evalúa a un valor temporal que no persiste más allá de la expresión.

A continuación algunos ejemplos de **usos incorrectos** de *lvalues* y *rvalues*:

```
// lvalues_and_rvalues2.cpp
int main()
{
   int i, j, *p;

   // Uso correcto: la variable i es un lvalue.
   i = 7;

   // Uso incorrecto: el operando a la izquierda debe ser un lvalue (C2106).
   7 = i; // C2106
   j * 4 = 7; // C2106

   // Uso correcto: el puntero desreferenciado es un lvalue.
   *p = i; 

   const int ci = 7;
   // Uso incorrecto: la variable es un valor no modificable (C3892).
   ci = 9; // C3892

   // Uso correcto: el operador condicional devuelve un lvalue.
   ((i < 3) ? i : j) = 7;
}
```

**TL;DR** (no es parte del original): A un *lvalue* le puedes asignar un valor (si no es `const`). A un *rvalue* no, pero puedes usarlo como el valor que asignas a un *lvalue*.

Comment: ¿Cómo se traduciría TL;DR? ¿Quizá DL;NLL (demasiado largo, no lo leí)?

Comment: ¿que hay de xvalues, glvalues, y prvalues? como para completar la respuesta

Comment: @rnrneverdies Me ha parecido que no era necesario ya que en la pregunta no se mencionan. Pero sí, sería una buena adición.

Comment: @Konamiman Yo creo que en español lo suyo sería usar simplemente **resumen** o algo similar, TL;DR es una abreviatura común en inglés pero no tenemos un equivalente y forzarlo añade más confusión de la que soluciona.

Comment: @rnrneverdies Quizás deberíamos llamarles *valores-i* y *valores-d* en castellano. [En las definiciones originales de estos términos en C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#Assignment:_l-values_and_r-values), un ***l**-value* era un valor que aparecía—o que podía aparecer—a la izquierda (***L**eft* en inglés) de `=`, y un ***r**-value* era uno que aparecía a la derecha (***R**ight* en inglés).  Bueno todo eso es una explicación fácil y corta, una que nos servía durante mucho años, pero en estos días C++ ha complicado esta historia bastante, como en todo lo demás.

Comment: @Konamiman, no entendí este ejemplo...

// Uso incorrecto: el operando a la izquierda debe ser un lvalue (C2106).
   7 = i; // C2106
   j * 4 = 7; // C2106

Comment: @Retr0 `j` no está definido, se le está asignando un valor a una expresión. Es un uso incorrecto por que primero se le tiene que asignar un valor persistente a `j`. La manera correcta sería `j  = 7 / 4`, la expresión a evaluar a la derechas.