# ¿Por qué este código que lo veo bien no me compila en c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int sumapares = 0;
int sumaimpares = 0;
int main()
{
    for(int numero = 50; numero<=60; numero +2)
    {
        sumapares = sumapares + numero;
    }

    for(int numero = 51; numero<60; numero +2)
    {
        sumaimpares = sumaimpares + numero; 
    }

    cout<<"la suma de los numeros pares es : " << sumapares << endl;
    cout<<"la suma de los numeros impares es : " << sumaimpares << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [tag:javascript], [tag:css]?

Comment: @lois6b quizá usa un compilador online jajaja

Comment: como así? arie. No entiendo lo que dices.

Comment: Era una broma en referencia a las etiquetas Javascript y css, ninguno tiene nada que ver con C++. Por otro lado, Puedes agregar el error que te da al compilar?

Answer (score 8):

A mi me compila perfectamente.

#### Problema.

Se queda en un bucle infinito porque los `for` no hacen avanzar la variable de control `numero`

#### Propuesta.

Cambia la instrucción de avance del bucle `for` por `numero += 2`:

```
for(int numero = 50; numero<=60; numero +=2)

...

for(int numero = 51; numero<60; numero +=2)
```

#### Posible mejora.

Puedes hacerlo todo en un solo bucle:

```
for (int numero = 50; numero <=60; ++numero)
{
    (numero % 2 ? sumaimpares : sumapares) += numero;
}
```

El truco usado en el código anterior es la combinación del operador ternario (`?:`) con el operador de incremento-asignación (`+=`) y la conversión implícita de entero a booleano.

El operador ternario (`?:`) evalúa una expresión y devuelve lo que haya tras el interrogante (`?`) en caso de que la expresión sea verdadera o lo que haya tras los dos puntos (`:`) en caso de que sea falsa, lo que no suele saberse es que el operador ternario funciona tanto como valor izquierdo como valor derecho (LValue y RValue<sup>1</sup>).

En el ejemplo anterior lo usamos de valor izquierdo, dicho valor será `sumaimpares` si la expresión `numero % 2` es verdadera y `sumapares` en caso de ser falsa. Pero el tipo de `numero % 2` es entero ¿Cómo se evalúa como si fuese booleano?

Todo valor numérico se convierte implícitamente a booleano siguiendo la lógica:

- Falso si es cero.
- Verdadero si no es cero.

Así pues, la expresión `numero % 2` devuelve `1` si el valor no es divisible por `2` (el residuo de dividir un número impar por dos es uno) y `0` si el valor es divisible por `2`. Dicho de otra manera: La expresión `numero % 2` evaluada como booleana es `true` si el número es impar y `false` si el número es par.

Por lo tanto, la expresión `(numero % 2 ? sumaimpares : sumapares)` será `sumaimpares` para cada `numero` impar y `sumapares` para cada `numero` par, a una u otra variable se le aplica la operación de incremento-asignación con la variable `numero` como valor derecho. A grandes rasgos el código sería equivalente a:

```
for (int numero = 50; numero <=60; ++numero)
{
    int *a_quien_sumo = nullptr;
    if ((numero % 2) != 0)
    {
        a_quien_sumo = &sumaimpares;
    }
    else
    {
        a_quien_sumo = &sumapares;
    }
    (*a_quien_sumo) = (*a_quien_sumo) + numero;
}
```

#### A tener en cuenta.

En general, no se aconseja usar `using namespace std;`, consulta [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460/por-qu%c3%a9-el-usar-using-namespace-std-se-considera-mala-pr%c3%a1ctica) para conocer el por qué.

Por otro lado, el uso de `std::endl` puede derivar en problemas de rendimiento porque vacía el búfer; aunque en un programa tan sencillo como el tuyo no supondrá ningún problema. Consulta [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47839/c-instrucci%c3%b3n-endl) para tener más detalles.

---

<sup>1</sup>Puedes consultar más sobre LValue y RValue [en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/914/diferencias-entre-rvalue-y-lvalue).

Comment: Podrías explicar la mejora, nunca había visto algo así. Gracias

Comment: @ElPatrón Sor pupuesto, he editado la pregunta.

Comment: @ArieCwHat efectivamente funciona. Puedes comprobarlo en tu compilador. El operador ternario no devuelve valores si no expresiones así que devuelve una u otra variable (no su contenido). En el ejemplo *equivalente* (que no igual) uso punteros, no referencias.

Comment: @ArieCwHat revisa tu código, porque [**funciona perfectamente**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wk4CINbWbSVvRyWz).

Comment: jajaja Lo siento, estaba imprimendo `numero` :P

Comment: @ArieCwHat ahora que lo comentas es cierto... lo siento :( se me da **muy mal** revisar código *encasquetado* en comentarios y se me pasó por alto lo que mencionas.

Answer (score 6):

En las líneas

```
for(int numero = 51; numero<60; numero +2)
```

No estas incrementando la variable `numero`, por lo que queda en un bucle infinito, cambialas a ambas por:

```
for(int numero = 51; numero<60; numero+=2)
```

Saludos!