# ¿Qué son las rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, y prvalues?

Tags: c++, c++11

Como continuación de la pregunta "[*Diferencias entre Rvalue y Lvalue*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/914/diferencias-entre-rvalue-y-lvalue)" y basado en la pregunta "[*What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)".

---

En C++03, una expresión podía ser **`rvalue`** o **`lvalue`**.

A partir de C++11, se añadieron tres nuevas categorías, siendo la lista completa de categorías:

1. **`rvalue`**: Valor del lado derecho (`r`ight `value`).
2. **`lvalue`**: Valor del lado izquierdo (`l`eft `value`).
3. **`xvalue`**: Valor en expiración (e`x`piring `value`).
4. **`glvalue`**: Valor del lado izquierdo generalizado (`g`eneralized `l`eft `value`).
5. **`prvalue`**: Valor del lado derecho puro (`p`ure `r`ight `value`).

De dos categorías hemos pasado a cinco.

- ¿Qué son estas nuevas categorías de expresiones?
- ¿Cómo se relacionan con las `rvalue` y `lvalue` que existían anteriormente?
- ¿Son las `rvalue` y `lvalue` de C++03 lo mismo que en C++11?
- ¿Por qué son necesarias estas categorías?

¿Acaso el [comité de estándares](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/)[image] tan sólo intenta confundirnos?

Comment: Yo casi pondría también las etiquetas C++14 (creo que no existe) y C++1Z (que habría que ir renombrándola a C++17)

Comment: @eferion gracias, lo olvidé. Como no me permitía aceptar la respuesta tras la publicación lo dejé ahí olvidado :'(

Comment: Si es normal, solo que como pasé por aquí pensé que sería buena idea mandar un recordatorio

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster La etiqueta [tag:expresión] me está trayendo problemas con usuarios que la quieren usar para regex (escriben "expresión" y un espacio). ¿Crees que se podría acotar con otro nombre más específico, sea `c++-expresión`, `expresión-de-c++`, `expresiones-rvalue-lvalue`, o similar?

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus estoy eliminando la etiqueta [tag:expresión] de la pregunta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Según el [estándar de C++[image]](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf)<sup>1</sup> (traducción mía):

> #### 3.10 `lvalues` y `rvalues`
>
> 1. Las expresiones se categorizan siguiendo la siguiente taxonomía:
>
> [image]
>
> - Una *lvalue* (así llamada por motivos históricos, ya que las lvalues pueden aparecer en el lado izquierdo de una expresión de asignación) designa una función o un objeto. [*Ejemplo:* si `E` es una expresión de tipo puntero, entonces `*E` es una expresión lvalue refiriéndose al objeto o función a la que `E` apunta. Como ejemplo adicional, el resultado de llamar a una función cuyo tipo de retorno es una referencia a lvalue es una lvalue. —*fin del ejemplo*]
> - Una *xvalue* (un valor "en eXpiración") se refiere a un objeto, habitualmente cerca del final de su ciclo de vida (que sus recursos vayan a ser movido, por ejemplo). Una xvalue es el resultado de ciertos tipos de expresiones que implican referencias rvalue. [*Ejemplo:* El resultado de llamar a una función cuyo tipo de retorno es una referencia rvalue es un xvalue. —*fin del ejemplo*]
> - Una *glvalue* (lvalue "generalizada") es una lvalue o una xvalue.
> - Una *rvalue* (así llamada por motivos históricos, ya que las rvalues pueden aparecer en el lado derecho de una expresión de asignación) es una xvalue, objeto temporal o subobjeto, también un valor que no está asociado con un objeto.
> - Una *prvalue* (valor del lado derecho "puro") es una rvalue que no es una xvalue. [*Ejemplo:* El resultado de llamar a una función cuyo tipo de retorno no sea una referencia es una prvalue. El valor de un literal como `12`, `7.3e5`, o `true` también es una prvalue. —*fin del ejemplo*]

Esto nos respondería qué son y cómo se relacionan entre si estas categorías de expresiones. Respecto a si `lvalue` y `rvalue` son iguales en C++03 y C++11, podemos afirmar que no del todo:

Las `lvalue` de C++03 conservan la misma categoría en C++11, mientras que las `rvalue` de C++03 son ahora las `prvalue` de C++11. En general podemos decir que las `rvalue` han evolucionado para tener en cuenta las [semánticas de movimiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Referencias_rvalue_y_los_move_constructor), lo cuál también responde al por qué son necesarias las nuevas categorizaciones ya que sin ellas, las semánticas de movimiento no serían posibles.

---

<sup>1</sup>Esa versión del estándar se publicó a finales de Marzo de 2010.