# aceptar valores de turnos string con nombres c++

Tags: c++, string

comunidad!
Adelanto lo que hace mi codigo en C++ , permite ingresar numeros, se pueden listar los numeros ingresados y se puede "borrar" el ultimo numero y seguir borrandolos hasta que no quede ninguno. Es un programa de turnos en fila, o cola.

Tratando (5 dias)... de hacer este mismo programa para que acepte un nombre, osea un string y no encuentro la forma. No quisiera borrar y empesar de nuevo por que me llevo tiempo hacer esto. mi principal problema parese ser los tipos de datos que al pasar valores, se me estropean completos.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
//#include <string>

using namespace std;
struct nodo
{
    int dato;
    struct nodo* Next;
};

typedef struct nodo *pilaPtr;
pilaPtr Nuevo, Inicio, Aux, P;

pilaPtr getfila(void)
{
    pilaPtr p;
    p = (pilaPtr)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    if (p != 0)
        p->Next = 0;
    return (p);
}

void freepila(pilaPtr p)
{
    free(p);
}

void Imprime()
{
    pilaPtr Aux;
    Aux = Inicio;

    if (Aux != 0)
    {
        do
        {
            cout << Aux->dato << "\t ";
            Aux = Aux->Next;

        } while (Aux != 0);
    }
}

void Agregar(int X)
{
    Nuevo = getfila();
    if (Nuevo != 0)
    {
        Nuevo->Next = Inicio;
        Inicio = Nuevo;
        Inicio->dato = X;
    }
}
void Menu()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n*Ingrese numeros de manera ascendente";
    cout << "\n*Recuerde su numero, espere ser llamado.";  
    cout << "\n                     ";
    cout << "\n                     ";
    cout << "\n1 AGREGAR UN NUMERO A LA FILA ";
    cout << "\n2 ELIMINAR ULTIMO NUMERO EN FILA";
    cout << "\n3 IMPRIMIR NUMEROS ACTIVOS";
    cout << "\n4 SALIR\n\n";
}
int main()
{
    int opcion = 0, X;
    do
    {
        Menu();
        cout << "\n SELECCIONE UNA OPCION: ";
        cin >> opcion;

        switch (opcion)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            cout << "\n INGRESE EL VALOR QUE QUIERA ";
            cin >> X;
            Agregar(X);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            P = Inicio;
            Inicio = P->Next;
            free(P);

            system("PAUSE");
            break;
        }
        case 3:
            Imprime();

            system("PAUSE");
            break;
        }
    } while (opcion != 4);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siendo la respuesta de [Mario Rodríguez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/66575/2742) válida, su respuesta olvida varias cosas que considero importante mencionar.

Para empezar, todo tu programa tiene [fugas de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuga_de_memoria); dado que estás trabajando en C++ podrías seguir el [patrón de diseño RAII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) para ayudarte a gestionar la memoria; bastaría con añadir un [destructor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_(inform%C3%A1tica)) a tu objeto `nodo`:

```
struct nodo
{
    std::string dato;
    nodo *Next = nullptr;
    // El destructor elimina los recursos dinamicos solicitados.
    ~nodo() { delete Next; }
};
```

Si te fijas, a diferencia de en tu código, no he añadido la palabra clave `struct` en la declaración del puntero a `nodo` además de usar `delete` en lugar de `free`. Esto es porque en C++ no es necesario usar `struct` para declarar objetos relacionados con estructuras y C++ usa el par `new`/`delete` en lugar del par `alloc`/`free`.

Por otro lado, he añadido una inicialización en el puntero `Next`, de esta manera el puntero tendrá el valor `nullptr` (literal de puntero nulo) al construir los objetos `nodo`; se considera una buena práctica inicializar todos los valores<sup>1</sup> siempre que no haya motivos para no hacerlo.

Teniendo en cuenta estas diferencias entre C y C++, tu función `getfila` debería quedar así:

```
using pilaPtr = nodo *;

pilaPtr getfila() try
{
    return new nodo;
}
catch (const std::bad_alloc &excepcion)
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

Una vez más hemos eliminado la palabra `struct` para declarar objetos relacionados con estructuras y en lugar de usar `typedef` hemos usado [alias de tipo](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias); el código que pusiste en `getfila` se ha vuelto completamente inútil porque:

1. No hay que comprobar el retorno de `malloc` (en C++ se usa `new`).
2. No hay que inicializar el miembro `nodo::Next` ya que le hemos añadido inicializador automático.
3. No se necesita una variable intermedia para guardar el retorno de `malloc`, como no debemos comprobarlo podemos devolverlo directamente.
4. No comprobamos el retorno de `new` porque esta funcionalidad nunca devuelve valores nulos, por el contrario: si fallase la solicitud de memoria se lanzaría una excepción de tipo [`std::bad_alloc`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc). Para comprobar si esta excepción se lanza usamos un bloque de [`try-catch` a nivel de función](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block).

Aunque siendo un programa tan sencillo, difícilmente te quedarás sin memoria, si lo consideras conveniente podrías evitar todo el bloque `try-catch`:

```
using pilaPtr = nodo *;

pilaPtr getfila()
{
    return new nodo;
}
```

Fíjate que en ningún caso hemos añadido el tipo de dato `void` a los paréntesis de la función para indicar que esta función no recibe datos, en C++ no es necesario hacerlo.

Tu función `freepila` debería quedar así:

```
void freepila(pilaPtr p)
{
    delete p;
}
```

Gracias a que hemos añadido un destructor en el objeto `nodo`, al borrar el puntero se borrarán [recursivamente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n_(ciencias_de_computaci%C3%B3n)) el nodo facilitado y todos sus hijos.

Para acabar, tu función `Agregar` podría quedar así:

```
void Agregar(std::string X)
{
    if ((Nuevo = getfila()))
    {
        Nuevo->Next = Inicio;
        Inicio = Nuevo;
        Inicio->dato = X;
    }
}
```

En C++ (creo que en C también) la comprobación de nulidad del retorno de `getfila` se puede hacer en la misma instrucción `if`, esto es porque una asignación es un [valor-del-lado-derecho](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/61306/qu%C3%A9-son-las-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-y-prvalues) y como tal se puede usar en una instrucción `if`<sup>2</sup>, pero hemos comentado que raramente este código devolverá un puntero nulo (considerando la implementación de `getfila` que puede devolverlo), así que podemos dejar la función `Agregar` así:

```
void Agregar(std::string X)
{
    Nuevo = getfila();
    Nuevo->Next = Inicio;
    Inicio = Nuevo;
    Inicio->dato = X;
}
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

1. No mezcles idiomas al programar: Es confuso que estés hablando de nodos (Español) que contienen punteros a Next (Inglés).
2. La función `freepila` es inútil (sólo hace una cosa) pero... si la tienes: úsala, en la opción `2` de tu menú llamas a `free` en lugar de a `freepila`.
3. Evita usar `using namespace std;`, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460/por-qu%c3%a9-el-usar-using-namespace-std-se-considera-mala-pr%c3%a1ctica) para saber más detalles de el por qué.
4. Las cabeceras pre-compiladas de `"stdafx.h"` no te van a ayudar en un programa tan pequeño, no las uses.
5. Para evitar las fugas de memoria, antes de finalizar `main` deberás añadir: `freepila(Inicio);`.
6. El programa, tal y como está, generará [corrupción de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrupci%C3%B3n_de_memoria) ya que intentará borrar punteros que ya han sido borrados; para evitarlo, cada vez que borres un nodo, deberías igualar a puntero nulo (`nullptr`) todos los punteros que lo apunten.

---

<sup>1</sup>El `dato` del `nodo` se inicializa automáticamente a cadena vacía.

<sup>2</sup>Muchos compiladores aconsejan añadir un par extra de paréntesis `(` y `)` por claridad, no porque sea en realidad necesario.

Answer (score 3):

Basta con cambiar la declaración del dato que lees y a continuación creas en la estructura. Me explico:

```
struct nodo
{
    string dato; // <--------------- cambiar de int a string
    struct nodo* Next;
};
```

Como es de tipo `string` el dato que vas a ir leyendo, su declaración dentro del `struct` debe ser del mísmo.

De igual forma hay que proceder en las funciones relacionadas con este dato. Basta con cambiar su declaración.

```
void Agregar(string X) // <----------- cambiar de int a string
{
    Nuevo = getfila();
    if (Nuevo != 0)
    {
        Nuevo->Next = Inicio;
        Inicio = Nuevo;
        Inicio->dato = X;
    }
}
```

Y, por último en el `main`:

```
int main()
{
    int opcion = 0 ;
    string X; // <--------------- cambiar de int a string
    do
    {
    ...
```

Sin olvidar, claro está, incluir la biblioteca `string` al inicio que en tu caso tienes comentada.

```
include <string>
```