# ¿En una operación, el operando izquierdo siempre debe ser lvalue y el derecho siempre será rvaluo, o pordría cambiar?

Tags: c++, contentvalues

Estaba investigando en Internet y me encontré con algunas páginas que decían que el lvalue siempre iba a la izquierda y me encontré con otras que decían que no siempre.

*¿Cual es la verdad?*

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿Responde a tu duda [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/61306/qué-son-las-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-y-prvalues)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La `l` y la `r` en `lvalue` y en `rvalue` estan por motivos historicos. Para simplificar
que es cada uno, lo veriamos de la siguiente manera:

```cpp
int numero = 5 + 5;
```

- ***lvalue:*** Todos los valores a los que le pongamos nombre. por ejemplo `numero` es un lvalue.
- ***rvalue:*** Son los valores a los que no les hemos asignado un nombre, son valores temporales. `5 + 5` es un rvalue, uno que solo existe momentáneamente y luego es asignado a un lvalue.

Pero, en realidad no tienen que estar del lado izquierdo el `lvalue` ni del derecho el `rvalue`. Fijate en el siguiente ejemplo:

```cpp
#include<string>

int main(void) {
    std::string s("Hola");
    s + s = s;
    return 0;
}
```

Es raro, pero el programa compila y corre. Lo que hace es crear un temporal o `rvalue` que va a almacenar el valor de `s+s` y despues a este `rvalue` se le asigna el valor de `s`, que es un `lvalue`. Entonces no es cierto lo que decian en las paginas, ambos pueden estar de cualquier lado.