# problemas con punteros dobles?

Tags: c++, funciones, punteros, c++11

Estoy tratando de pasar una función que retorna un puntero `*Get()` , a una función que recibe un puntero doble `view(int **)`  , pero no entiendo el error , se supone que si hago esto `view(&Get())`   la función debe recibir la dirección en donde esta almacenado el puntero . el codigo es el siguiente :

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin; 
using std::cin; 
using std::cout; 
using std::string; 
using std::endl;  

int *Get();
void view(int **) ; 
int main()
{
    view(&Get()) ; **El error lo genera esta linea**
    return 0 ;  
}
int *Get()
{
    int *P = new int[5]; 
    for(int i=0; i!=5; i++){*(P+i) = i+5 ; } 
    return P; 
}

void view(int **a)
{
   cout <<"direcion get->"<< a << endl ;
   cout <<"direcion *get->"<< *a << endl ; 
   cout <<"direcion **get->"<< **a << endl ;  
}
```

el error que arroja el compilado es el siguiente

```
 lvalue required as unary '&' operand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Como comenta **Eequiis Vásquez** estas pasando por referencia el resultado de la función que se aloja en una **variable temporal (rvalue)** y C++ no lo permite. Por lo que es necesario almacenar su valor en una **variable (lvalue)**.

**Para solucionarlo, utilice **una variable para almacenar el resultado de Get()**.**

Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin; 
using std::cin; 
using std::cout; 
using std::string; 
using std::endl;  

int *Get();
void view(int **) ; 
int main()
{
    int *p = Get();
    view(&p) ;
    return 0 ;  
}
int *Get()
{
    int *P = new int[5]; 
    for(int i=0; i!=5; i++){*(P+i) = i+5 ; } 
    return P; 
}

void view(int **a)
{
   cout <<"direcion get->"<< a << endl ;
   cout <<"direcion *get->"<< *a << endl ; 
   cout <<"direcion **get->"<< **a << endl ;  
}
```

Comment: La solución está bien, pero la explicación no. No se intenta pasar la función por referencia porque es una llamada por los paréntesis. Lo que se intenta pasar por referencia es la dirección del resultado, que es una variable temporal (rvalue), y eso C++ no lo permite. Al guardar el resultado en una variable (lvalue) se soluciona el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación. Me lo apunto para los futuros conocimientos y voy a editar la respuesta, para que pueda ayudar a alguien en el futuro en base a tu comentario.

Answer (score 2):

`Get()` es un [rvalue](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/914/diferencias-entre-rvalue-y-lvalue). No se puede aplicar el `&` operador al rvalue. Ver tu mensaje de error:

```
lvalue required as unary '&' operand
```

Variables son lvalues, pero valores intermedios, como resultados de funciones, son rvalues. Entonces, necesitas introducir una variable:

```
int* p = Get();
view(&p);
```

Una nota al margen: en programación de C++ moderna, preferimos punteros inteligentes y `std::vector`. También, `P[i]` es siempre mejor que `*(P+i)`.