# ¿Como aplicar semantica de movimiento en C++?

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de crear una clase que gestiona la memoria de un array de enteros con sus respectivos metodos constructor de copia, el destructor y el operador de asignacion de copia, pero no entiendo bien como se hacen los metodos con la semantica de movimiento.

```
class IntArray{
    int size_;
    int *array_; // puntero a entero
public:
    IntArray(int size);
    IntArray(const IntArray &other);            // constructor de copia
    ~IntArray();                                // destructor
    IntArray &operator=(const IntArray &other); // asignacion de copia
};
```

entiendo que tienen que ser un constructor y un operador de asignacion

```
IntArray(IntArray &&other);
IntArray &operator=(IntArray &&other);
```

pero que logica tienen que tener los metodos para que funcionen??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero debes saber qué es un *lvalue* y un *rvalue*.

En pocas palabras, un *lvalue* es una variable, que puede aparecer tanto a la derecha como a la izquierda de una expresión. Un *rvalue* es un valor temporal que solo puede aparecer a la derecha.

Por ejemplo:

```
// n es un lvalue y 1 es un rvalue
int n = 1;

// x también es un lvalue
// n no deja de ser un lvalue
int x = n;
```

Si necesitas profundizar, aquí hay algunas preguntas sobre el tema:

- [Diferencias entre Rvalue y Lvalue](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/914/169744)
- [¿Qué son las rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, y prvalues?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/61306/169744)

---

Existen 2 tipos de referencias, una a *lvalue*s y otra a *rvalue*s. Se denotan con `&` y `&&` respectivamente.

Por lo tanto el constructor y el operador de movimiento, reciben un valor temporal. Está a punto de morir, así que puedes tomar lo que quieras de este objeto y ahorrarte trabajo.

En tu caso, es conveniente implementarlos así:

```
IntArray(IntArray &&other) {
    // Nos quedamos con la memoria que ya reservó el otro objeto
    array_ = other.array_;
    size_ = other.size_;

    // Y le quitamos el puntero para que el destructor no la libere
    other.array_ = nullptr;
}

IntArray &operator=(IntArray &&other){
    // Si se llama este operador, seguramente el objeto
    // ya haya reservado memoria, así que la liberamos
    delete[] array_;

    // Y hacemos lo mismo que en el constructor
    array_ = other.array_;
    size_ = other.size_;

    other.array_ = nullptr;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: al operador de asignacion solo le falta retornar el objeto del puntero this, por lo demas lo entendi, la logica es que nos quedamos con las propiedades del objeto other.

Comment: @Eipo cierto. Bien visto.

Answer (score 3):

#### Introducción.

Para entender las semánticas de movimiento, hay que entender los objetos temporales de C++. Un objeto temporal es un objeto que se crea como parte de una expresión y que se destruirá cuando la expresión finalice. Sin entrar en detalles pues resultaría en una respuesta demasiado larga, te muestro dos ejemplos típicos de objetos temporales en C++:

1. Llamadas a función.

   ```cpp
   void f(std::string s) { … }

   …

   f("Hola mundo!"); // <-- Aquí hay un objeto temporal!
   ```

   la función recibe un objeto `std::string` pero la estamos llamando con un literal de cadena (cuyo tipo es `char[12]`), así que se construye un `std::string` temporal y anónimo el cuál será copiado (con el constructor de copia de `std::string`) en el argumento de la función.
2. Conversiones implícitas.

   ```cpp
   struct S { S(int) { … } };

   …

   S s = 1; // <-- Aquí hay un objeto temporal!
   ```

   El objeto `S` es construible con un entero (`int`) así que podemos usar un entero para asignarlo a una instancia de `S`. Esto crea un objeto `S` temporal y anónimo con el constructor `S::S(int)` el cuál después se copiará a la instancia `s` con el operador de asignación `S &operator=(const S &)`.

Ambos puntos son más o menos lo mismo, pero sirven para entender el concepto en diferentes contextos.

#### Ejemplo.

Las semánticas de movimiento se añadieron a C++ en el estándar C++11 como solución a los problemas de rendimiento que supone hacer continuamente copias de objetos (con constructor de copia u operador de asignación) que se iban a descartar (los temporales). A partir de dicho estándar es posible hacer referencia y nombrar los objetos temporales mediante una ROT "*Referencia a Objeto Temporal*" (*RValue reference* en inglés); la sintaxis de una ROT es `tipo &&nombre`, fíjate que el `&&` no es el operador *AND* en este contexto.

Con la capacidad de poder referenciar temporales podemos reescribir los ejemplos anteriores:

```cpp
#define P std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';

void f(const std::string &s) { P; }
void f(std::string &&s) { P; }

struct S
{
    S(int) { P; }
    S(const S &) { P; }
    S(S &&) { P; }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string holamundo = "Hola mundo!";
    f("Hola mundo!");
    f(std::string{});
    f(holamundo);

    S s1 = 1;
    S s2{std::move(S{2})};

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior muestra la siguiente salida:

```
void f(string&&)
void f(string&&)
void f(const string&)
S::S(int)
S::S(int)
S::S(S&&)
```

#### Explicación y excepciones.

Las dos primeras llamadas a `f` se hicieron con un temporal y en consecuencia se llamó la versión de la función que acepta temporales. En cuanto a la segunda construcción de `S`, hemos necesitado llamar a la función `std::move` para que el constructor de movimiento sea llamado ¿Por qué? y por cierto ¿Por qué no se ve el constructor de copia de `S` en la salida?.

Los compiladores C++ llevan a cabo una optimización conocida como "*elisión de copia*", esta optimización consiste en detectar objetos que deberían ser copiados de un contexto a otro para en lugar de construir-y-copiar, construirlos directamente en el contexto final, por eso no se ve el constructor de copia de `S` en la salida y por eso necesitamos usar `std::move` para forzar la llamada al constructor de movimiento… ya que de lo contrario se lanzaría una *elisión de copia*.

Antes de C++17 la *elisión de copia* no estaba estandarizada y quedaba al criterio del compilador aplicarla o no, a partir de C++17 la *elisión de copia* está garantizada siempre que sea posible por lo que muchas semánticas de movimiento se llevan a cabo sin RAT ni los constructores/operadores asociados.

Answer (score 1):

Si ya has definido un constructor de copia

```
IntArray(const IntArray &other);
```

Entonces no es necesario que añadas el operador de asignación

```
IntArray &operator=(const IntArray &other); // asignacion de copia
```

Al realizar una copia por asignación, por ejemplo en...

```
IntArray a(10);
IntArray b = a;
```

Se invocará automaticamente al constructor de copia.
En la implementación de este contructor de copia debes:

1. copiar el valor de *size_* del IntArray que te pasan por parametro;
2. inicializar *array_* con *size_* bytes de memoria
3. copiar la memoria de other.array_ en el nuevo array_ (usando memcpy, por ejemplo)

Comment: Sí es necesario. Cuando asignas la variable en la declaración se ejecuta el constructor correspondiente. Las próximas veces que asignas la variable se ejecuta el operador.